# Issue in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

I'm new to EF Core and I have a problem in this section (`Startup.cs`):

```
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt => 
{
    opt.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});
```

The `DataContext` is a `.cs` file, in the `Persistence` folder, and it's a class that derives from `DbContext`.

When I write in above of `Startup.cs`:

```
using Persistnece;
using Microsoft.EntityFramewormCore;
```

Visual Studio Code throws an error :

> Remove unnecessary using !?

and when I use

```
dotnet ef migration add InitialCreate -p Persistence/ -s API/
```

command, the result is

> Build start .. Build failed

What is the problem?

**Note**: I have downloaded `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.sqlite`

See the error that appears in the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: `remove unnecessary usings` is a warning and does not stop the build. In visual Studio, make sure errors are enabled to see the error, and also check the 'Build Output' in the Output window for more information as to why the build fails.

Comment: the error in services.AddDbContext<DataContext> .. DataContext <- , and in UseSqlite <-

Comment: right, that's better. Please add the full code in that function, and the actual error message you see to the question 

Comment: Shouldn't *using Persist**ne**ce* be *using Persist**en**ce*?

Comment: yes i use using Persistence